# onmousseout event and live search ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with a live search box and onmouseout event , after typing a keyword on search box and results has been displayed i want my data( results )
disappear once i am hovering out of the div, if the user moves his mousse out of the div , no results should stay at the div .
my first problem is my onmouseout event function now is working on every single result, that's mean that when i move my mousse from the first ligne result to the second or the third... it enables the on mousse out effect !!
i want the event to applied for the entire div not on individual elements of my div .
my second strange problem that once results has been displayed if i move my mousse next to elements from my menu bar ex: BLOG or LOGIN it apply the onmouseout event!! it's like that my menu is also a listener.. thing that should not be at all..
can you help me to find a soltion to thses problems ??
this is my site's urli built my site on mvc conception, this is my script 
index.html

```
<form action="" id="searchform" method="POST">

                <p>
                    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Chercher" size="30" name="search" size="30" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)">
                    <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit"></button><br />


                </p>

            </form><!--/ #searchform-->

            <div id="livesearch" style="margin-top:-10px; text-align : center;padding:0px 20px 0px 0px ;display : block;width:400px; background: rgba(540, 954, 554, 0.5);" onmouseout ="funcm()"></div>
```

ajax call and onmousseout function

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function showResult(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.position = "absolute";


    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","/search?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function changeDisplay(element, display) {

    element.style.display = display;
    return;
}

var dataContainer = document.getElementById("livesearch");
var dataContainer2 = document.getElementById("test");

function funcm() {
    changeDisplay(dataContainer, "none");



}

            </script>
```

and search file

```
        $vall  = "<div id='test' style='display : block; position:relative ;><p>";
        if($_GET['q']){
            $this->value = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : null;
         $val = $this->model->getData($this->value);
        }else{
            $this->value='';
        }
        if(!empty($val ))
        {
        foreach ($val as $key => $valuee){
         $vall .= "<a href='/index'>".$valuee['TitleTag'].'</a><br />';
        }}
        echo $vall.'</p></div>';
    }
```

my model file

```
 public function getData($key)
                        {
                           $data;
                           $key = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($key)));
                                 $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT  id FROM mytable WHERE mytitles LIKE '%{$key}%'");
                                                                            $sth->execute();
                                                                            $data = $sth->fetchAll();
                                    return $data;

                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:
Add autocomplete="off" attribute to the form, it's a little bit annoying

```
<input id="search" type="text" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" name="search" size="30" placeholder="Chercher" autocomplete="off">
```

Second: 
Set higher z-index to #livesearch and change display style to display:none

```
<div id="livesearch" style="margin-top: -10px; text-align: center; padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px; width: 400px; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; position: absolute; border: 0px none; display: none; z-index: 9999;">
```

Third:
Remove inline onmouseout ="funcm()" and add this code bellow the ajax call

```
var livesearch = document.getElementById('livesearch');
livesearch.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  changeDisplay(this, "block");
}, false);

livesearch.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  changeDisplay(this, "none");
}, false);
```

For me it works on your page, I've checked in firebug.

Comment: thanks Konrad this is the result http://goo.gl/Qfcx0Y  its floating left ..and menu bar little bit changed

Comment: are you sure you have made the changes exactly as pointed above?

Comment: i made these changes you pointed above and yes it worked the only issue some huge margins between my logo and my menu bar , and suddenly the width of my menu bar changed floated little bit right also the livesearch div floated left so  i removed these changes and i am testing it on my localhost thank youu

Comment: edited my answer a little bit, provide me any test page if you can

Comment: and i see now results stay at div even if i am hovering out

Comment: there is some mess in html put <nav> outside the <div class="widget-container widget_search"> like before
end result should be like this: https://vid.me/ui2Z

Comment: yes great i closed the div before nav bar .. only issue now is results should not stay on div when i mouve out my mousse

Comment: the changeDisplay functioan was removed

    function changeDisplay(element, display) {

        element.style.display = display;
        return;
    }

It is used in the listeners please put in into script again

Comment: I am glad I could help